# mdadm not enough to start array - /dev/sdc2 no superblock

Tags: mdadm, superblock

After a power failure on a server with 4 disks in RAID6 configuration, /dev/md1 won't come up (though /dev/md0 does).

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/1 assembled from 3 drives - not enough to start the array while not clean - consider --force.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
>: mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2 /dev/sde2 -v
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md1
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sdc2/: Not a directory
mdadm: /dev/sdc2/ has no superblock - assembly aborted
>: mdadm --examine /dev/sdc2
Magic: a92b4efc
Raid Level: raid6
Raid devices: 4
...
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
Checksum : 24c01b72 - correct
Array State : AAA
```

But when I look at the other raid md0, it looks fine:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : Active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdb1[0] sde1[3] sdd1[2] sdc1[1]
    124932095 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

and when I use mdadm --examine on /dev/sdc1 it looks about the same as /dev/sdc2 but apparently isn't corrupt. I trying restoring alternate superblocks on /dev/sdc2 like:

```
>: e2fsck /dev/sdc2
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc2
...
you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or 
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
>: e2fsck -b 8193
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc2
```

Is there any other way I can fix the bad magic number except the two alternate superblocks (I tried both)?  I looked at the 3 other volumes in the raid array and they say the same thing as /dev/sdc2, they can't all be corrupt, can they? How do I restore them? Here's the partition table for each of the four drives:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, xxxxxxx
Disklabel type: gpt
Device    Start     End    Sectors   Size  Type
/dev/sdc1 xxxx      xxxx    xxxx     59.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc2 xxxx      xxxx    xxxx     2.7T  Linux RAID
```

note: was typing earlier from screenshots since ssh wouldn't come up, now it's up so I can cut/paste:

First drive in md1:

```
>: mdadm -E /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee) 

>: fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D724DBDE-FC51-4BA1-AF65-01C21E6D1846
Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048  124999679  124997632 59.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  124999680 5860532223 5735532544  2.7T Linux RAID
```

partition 2 where md1 volume lives:

```
>: mdadm -E /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x1
 Array UUID : 31731ada:b0804a8a:a69cbab4:505c2adf
       Name : kvmhost4:1  (local to host kvmhost4)
Creation Time : Fri Nov  3 12:52:05 2017
 Raid Level : raid6
Raid Devices : 4
Avail Dev Size : 5735270400 (2734.79 GiB 2936.46 GB)
 Array Size : 5735270400 (5469.58 GiB 5872.92 GB)
Data Offset : 262144 sectors
 Super Offset : 8 sectors
Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
      State : active
Device UUID : ee3768a3:397f01ad:6086d77f:222b5e8d
Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
Update Time : Wed Jul 29 15:24:04 2020
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
   Checksum : 190180d - correct
     Events : 16450527
     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K
 Device Role : Active device 0
 Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Now the second volume in the raid 6, /dev/sdc

```
>: mdadm -E /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)

>: mdadm -E /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x0
 Array UUID : 3e7427b8:e82071a4:8224a7b7:f4dc6d0f
       Name : kvmhost4:0  (local to host kvmhost4)
 Creation Time : Fri Nov  3 12:51:44 2017
 Raid Level : raid6
 Raid Devices : 4
 Avail Dev Size : 124932096 (59.57 GiB 63.97 GB)
 Array Size : 124932096 (119.14 GiB 127.93 GB)
Data Offset : 65536 sectors
Super Offset : 8 sectors
Unused Space : before=65448 sectors, after=0 sectors
      State : clean
Device UUID : dd82716f:49b276d7:9d383a43:06cf9206
Update Time : Fri Jul 10 06:20:40 2020
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
   Checksum : c2291539 - correct
     Events : 37
     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 1
Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

partition 2 where md1 partition lives

```
>: mdadm -E /dev/sdc2
/dev/sdc2:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x1
 Array UUID : 31731ada:b0804a8a:a69cbab4:505c2adf
       Name : kvmhost4:1  (local to host kvmhost4)
Creation Time : Fri Nov  3 12:52:05 2017
 Raid Level : raid6
 Raid Devices : 4
Avail Dev Size : 5735270400 (2734.79 GiB 2936.46 GB)
 Array Size : 5735270400 (5469.58 GiB 5872.92 GB)
Data Offset : 262144 sectors
Super Offset : 8 sectors
Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
      State : active
Device UUID : b5d3a4ac:e353b079:3c77d4fe:39cda55b
Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
Update Time : Wed Jul 29 15:24:04 2020
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
   Checksum : 24c01b72 - correct
     Events : 16450527
     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 1
Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

drive 3 in the volume /dev/sdd:

```
>: mdadm -E /dev/sdd2
/dev/sdd2:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x1
 Array UUID : 31731ada:b0804a8a:a69cbab4:505c2adf
       Name : kvmhost4:1  (local to host kvmhost4)
Creation Time : Fri Nov  3 12:52:05 2017
 Raid Level : raid6
Raid Devices : 4
Avail Dev Size : 5735270400 (2734.79 GiB 2936.46 GB)
 Array Size : 5735270400 (5469.58 GiB 5872.92 GB)
Data Offset : 262144 sectors
Super Offset : 8 sectors
Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
      State : active
Device UUID : 5399392a:dfbadbbf:f6d4148d:ff796dc2
Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
Update Time : Wed Jul 29 15:24:04 2020
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
   Checksum : dd88528c - correct
     Events : 16450527
     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 2
Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

And drive 4 of the array:

```
>: mdadm -E /dev/sde2
/dev/sde2:
      Magic : a92b4efc
    Version : 1.2
Feature Map : 0x9
 Array UUID : 31731ada:b0804a8a:a69cbab4:505c2adf
       Name : kvmhost4:1  (local to host kvmhost4)
Creation Time : Fri Nov  3 12:52:05 2017
 Raid Level : raid6
Raid Devices : 4
Avail Dev Size : 5735270400 (2734.79 GiB 2936.46 GB)
 Array Size : 5735270400 (5469.58 GiB 5872.92 GB)
Data Offset : 262144 sectors
Super Offset : 8 sectors
Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
      State : active
Device UUID : 5230e8e3:792ce23c:8431a3f1:99d5bfef
Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
Update Time : Mon Jul  6 13:10:59 2020
Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors - bad blocks present.
   Checksum : a5d7e1fa - correct
     Events : 13500044
     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 3
Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Comment: Stop running random commands on RAID members. Provide full unshortened unaltered mdadm --examine output for each RAID member.

Comment: I couldn't bring up ssh, so typing from screenshots, managed to disable md1 and bring box up, will post output to original post

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working (I think) by doing:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --force
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md/1 as 'clean'
mdadm: /dev/md/1 has been started with 3 drives (out of 4).
>: cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md1 : active raid6 sdb2[0] sdd2[2] sdc2[1]
  5735270400 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [UUU_]
  [>....................]  resync =  0.0% (765440/2867635200) finish=561.7min speed=85048K/sec
  bitmap: 4/22 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdb1[0] sde1[3] sdd1[2] sdc1[1]
  124932096 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
unused devices: <none>
```

Now I will wait for it to re-sync and attempt a reboot. Meanwhile, the volume mounts and I got my data back!